# tsconfig.json ignored on build

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have project with TypeScript, where in folder with `.ts` files resides `tsconfig.json` configured with

```
outFile: 'somefile.js' // for bundling in single output file
compileOnSave: true   // does this need comment?
```

If I save any `.ts` file, the output is generated according to setting in `tsconfig.json`, but if I re-/build the project, the VS generetes separate `.js` and `.js.map` files for every `.ts` files like if `tsconfig.json` does not exists.

If I remove typescript settings from `.csproj` file, the separate files are not generated, but I got errors on build, because VS is unable to read target EcmaScript version from `tsconfig.json` and it fallback to `ES3` which my code is not compatible with.

I'm using VS2015 update 3. Are there any hack to make VS respect my `tsconfig.json` on build?